# website blinks since header code is loaded from a different file

Tags: javascript, html, include, flicker, blink

I am developing a website from scratch and I realized that instead of having the header (banner+horizontal navigation menu) code in each html page, it would be more efficient to have it in a separate HTML file and use the JS load function in every page's body, so I can modify the header in only one file to apply changes to the whole website instead of wasting time modifying it on every page.

problem is since I made that change using :

```
<script>
$("#header").load("header_eng.html");
</script>
```

in every page's body (where header_eng is an html file containing my header code), my website started to "blink" between each page. Now when I navigate the website, the banner image, for example, blinks/flickers between pages instead of just staying there.

I did not have this problem when my header code was in every page's code.

here is the example of the website with the header code in every page file :
https://cbrieuc.github.io/index.html
(only the two first pages are up for the first example so just spam the link "About Me" or "News" to check for blinking)

and here with the "load" function instead :
https://cbrieuc.github.io/index_eng.html

here is what the code looks like for a page using the "load function"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>BRIEUC COUILLEROT</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="header"></div></br>
<div id=corps>
<pre>
test
</pre>
</div>

<!--loading header from header.html-->
<script>
$("#header").load("header_eng.html");
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Any idea what occured?
by the way i'm quite new to web development!

Comment: It's not quite related to your question, but if you're using `github.io` (GitHub Pages) you can use [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) for free. It's a static site generator that automates lots of stuff, like making sure all your pages have your header and footers. It takes some setting up, but it's easier than setting up something like PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the javascript is being executed after page load. You need to include your header file using a server side language like php

Comment: Is there no way to achieve what I'm looking for without php? i have tried it with Php but mozilla firefox wouldn't read my index.php at all.. so I assumed too many visitors would have the same problem.

Comment: @nekomata move the javascript to the top of the body, just after the opening body tag.

Comment: @nekomata This is a bad practice as network issues could cause the initial page to be unresponsive. The best practice for using includes like this is to build the response server-side.

Comment: @Josh Jackson unfortunately moving the javascript where you pointed at didn't work, the page doesn't load the header anymore, just the rest of the content ( the "test" div in that case)

Comment: @nekomata because the #header div hasnt been create yet, my mistake. Move the javascript to after the <div id="header"></div>

Comment: @Josh Jackson That fix seems to have an interesting effect, the page doesn't flicker anymore if I spam the "About me" link with a certain time interval, like a few seconds. But If I spam it with no time interval, it still flickers whereas it doesn't on the first example.

Comment: I would really recommend using a server side language. If you are using PHP you can use `require_once "path/to/file.php";`

Comment: @Josh Jackson well, I guess there's no way around php here... I'm just worried that many people won't be able to read my php files in their browsers.. I might come back to my original set up with the header code in every page. Thanks for the fast replies!

Comment: @nekomata, Your php files wont be read 'in-browser' anyway, php is a server side language and runs soley on the server, not ever in the broswer, it only sends responses and actions/requests to the browser..